# Is there a way to get the last executed JavaScript Command?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way some sort of built in Javascript function that either returns the last line of javascript code (and source of code) executed or the last function that was executed?

Comment: Nope. Sounds like an XY problem so far; why are you trying to do this?

Comment: In a Node.js REPL, the `_` character will give you the *result* of the last statement evaluated on the command line, but not the last statement itself. (but if you're in a REPL, you can also just use the up arrow key, and also `_` isn't influenced by statements most recently evaluated in a background task like `setInterval`.) As suggested above -- what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Write your own parser...